# Knees feel stressed when going into deadlift position

Tags: deadlifts, hip

Whenever bend my knees after hip hinging, I feel quite a bit of stress on my kness. What muscles maybe causing this problem, and how can I develop them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Pain in training: What do?](https://www.barbellmedicine.com/blog/pain-in-training-what-do/)

The short answer: reduce the training dose. The linked article from Barbell Medicine has lots of excellent information about pain, but the short version is that when you have pain in training, it’s because the dose has been too high for some amount of time.

To remedy this, you need to find your entry point back into the movement where you don’t have pain. This can be as simple as reducing the load, or might require you to be more creative by modifying the movement. But only you can figure this out. Once you’ve found your entry point, slowly increase the training stress from there over a number of weeks until you are able to train as hard as you like.

Beyond this, it’s impossible to say why your knees are hurting without significantly more detail, and even then, identifying the root cause of pain is fuzzy at best outside of circumstances involving acute trauma.